# Passing adapter to fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

I have made toolbar as fragment and now want to pass recycler view adapter to that fragment so that i can show filter results in the recycler view,
Can anyone help me that how i can pass the adapter to fragment and display the results.
This is my toolbar fragment which i have called in the activity where recycler view

```
class toolbarFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        ......
        if (searchView != null) {
            searchView!!.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(activity?.componentName))
            queryTextListener = object : SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
              ....

                override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean {
                    /**Need to apply filter on recycler view here**/
                    //RoomActivity.adapter.filter.filter(query)
                    return true
                }
            }
        }

}
```

Here is my activity code

```
//adding toolbar
val toolbar = toolbarFragment()
val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment, toolbar, toolbar.javaClass.simpleName)
fragmentTransaction.commit()

.....

adapter = roomItemsAdapter(rooms)
recycler_view.adapter = adapter
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

Comment: Please show us some codes of what you already have tried. Use edit button and add some codes to the question.

Comment: @ʍѳђઽ૯ท i have edited teh question with some code

Answer (score 0):

This function queried with RoomDB return list, you can update recyclerview

```
  override fun onQueryTextSubmit(query: String?): Boolean { return true}
```